# aspx page not load in iframe click on button

Tags: c#, asp.net, modalpopupextender

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="hiddenPopupPatientRegistration" Style="display: none" />
    <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="popupPatientRegistration" runat="server" PopupControlID="panelPatientRegistration"
        TargetControlID="hiddenPopupPatientRegistration" BackgroundCssClass="cssmodalbackground"
        BehaviorID="modalBehaviour" CancelControlID="btnClose">
    </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
    <div id="panelPatientRegistration" class="cssmodalpopup" style="display: none">
        <iframe id="iframePatientRegistration"  class="csstable" runat="server" width="600px"
            height="485px" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server" CssClass="cssbutton" Text="Close" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          iframePatientRegistration.Attributes["src"] = "Patient_Registration.aspx?flowType=" + flowType + "&fromTime=" + hidFromTime.Value + "&toTime=" + hidToTime.Value + "&acqModalityID=" + hidAcqModalityID.Value + "&schLocationID=" + ddlScheduledProcedureStepLocation.SelectedValue;
            popupPatientRegistration.Show();
    }
```

I have to show aspx page in modal popup extender control.
 And pass values through query string
 BUT ASPX page not loads in Iframe.code behind.

when i see html source then getting these two lines

```
<HTML>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

the display property for the containing Div "panelPatientRegistration" is set to none. The iframe is inside that and it never gets rendered.

Comment: Gayatri i have reloved Style on panel even then page not renderede

Answer (score 0):

Collect all your Querystring data and save them in hidden fields and write javascript function where change the src of the Iframe by passing the values as querystrings using Hidden fields.

```js
    <script>
        function changeIframSrc(src) {
            document.getElementById('<%=iframePatientRegistration.ClientID %>').src = src;
        }
    </script>
```

the problem i saw in the code is you are clicking a server side button where the page is getting posted back and even though you are changing the src of the iframe but controls are getting created again due to the postback. so use the javascript function above to call that particular page and pass the querystrings using the hidden fields solve the issue.